# how to remove subviews from scrollview?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

how do i remove all subviews from my scrollview...

i have a uiview and a button above it in the scrollview something like this....

here is my code to add subview in scroll view

```
-(void)AddOneButton:(NSInteger)myButtonTag {
lastButtonNumber = lastButtonNumber + 1;

if ((lastButtonNumber == 1) || ((lastButtonNumber%2) == 1)) {
btnLeft = 8;}
else if ((lastButtonNumber == 2) || ((lastButtonNumber%2) == 0)) {
btnLeft = 162;
}
CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(btnLeft, btnTop, 150, 150);
CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(btnLeft, btnTop, 150, 150);
UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
Button.frame = frame1;
Button.tag = myButtonTag;
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[Button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"WaitScreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    GraphThumbViewControllerobj = [[GraphThumbViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:[[GraphIdArray objectAtIndex:myButtonTag]intValue]];
    GraphThumbViewControllerobj.view.frame=frame2;
    GraphThumbViewControllerobj.lblCounter.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d",myButtonTag+1,flashCardsId.count];
    GraphThumbViewControllerobj.lblQuestion.text=[flashCardText objectAtIndex:myButtonTag];
    [myScrollView addSubview:GraphThumbViewControllerobj.view];


[myScrollView addSubview:Button];


if ((lastButtonNumber == 2) || ((lastButtonNumber%2) == 0)) {
btnTop = btnTop + 162;
}
if (btnTop+150 > myScrollView.frame.size.height) {
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((myScrollView.frame.size.width), (btnTop+160));}
}
```

and here is the code to remove subviews

```
if(myScrollView!=nil)
{
        while ([myScrollView.subviews count] > 0) {
            //NSLog(@"subviews Count=%d",[[myScrollView subviews]count]);
            [[[myScrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 104, accepted):

To remove all the subviews from any view, you can iterate over the subviews and send each a `removeFromSuperview` call:

```
// With some valid UIView *view:
for(UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This is entirely unconditional, though, and will get rid of **all** subviews in the given view. If you want something more fine-grained, you could take any of several different approaches:

- Maintain your own arrays of views of different types so you can send them `removeFromSuperview` messages later in the same manner
- Retain all your views where you create them and hold on to pointers to those views, so you can send them `removeFromSuperview` individually as necessary
- Add an `if` statement to the above loop, checking for class equality. For example, to only remove all the UIButtons (or custom subclasses of UIButton) that exist in a view, you could use something like:

```
// Again, valid UIView *view:
for(UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    } else {
        // Do nothing - not a UIButton or subclass instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one mate. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 38):

An old question; but as it's the first hit on Google for this I thought I'd also make a note that there's also this method:

```
[[myScrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

You can't do the isKindOfClass check with this, but it's still a good solution to know about.

Edit: Another point to note is that the scrollbar of a scrollview is added as a subview to that scrollview. Thus if you iterate through all the subviews of a scrollview you will come across it. If removed it'll add itself again - but it's important to know this if you're only expecting your own UIView subclasses to be in there.

Amendment for Swift 3:

```
myScrollView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Answer (score 9):

To add to what Tim said, I noticed that you are tagging your views. If you wanted to remove a view with a certain tag you could use:

```
[[myScrollView viewWithTag:myButtonTag] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you should use the fast enumeration suggestion.

```
for(UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
   [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Isn't this supposed to throw an exception if you change the collection being iterated? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW3

This example may be better.

```
NSArray *subviews = [[scroller subviews] copy];
for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
[subviews release];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the UIScrollView and others subclass of UIView is that they contains initially some views (like the vertical and horizontal scrollbar for the UIScrollView). So i created a category of UIView to delete the Subviews filtered on the class.

For example:

```
[UIScrollView removeAllSubviewsOfClass:[FooView class],[BarView class],nil];
```

The code:

```
- (void)removeAllSubviewsOfClass:(Class)firstClass, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;


- (void)removeAllSubviewsOfClass:(Class)firstClass, ...
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FALSEPREDICATE"];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstClass);

    for (Class class = firstClass; class != nil; class = va_arg(args, Class)) 
    {
        predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicate,[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass:%@",class], nil]];
    }

    va_end(args);
    [[self.subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest is to use

```
for(UIView *subview in [scrollView subviews])
{
  [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This indeed causes crash as the basic rule is array shouldn't modified while being enumerated, to prevent that we can use

```
[[scrollView subviews] 
           makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

But sometimes crash is still appearing because makeObjectsPerformSelector: will enumerate and performs selector, Also in iOS 7 ui operations are optimized to perform more faster than in iOS 6, Hence the best way to iterate array reversely and remove

```
NSArray *vs=[scrollView subviews];
for(int i=vs.count-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    [((UIView*)[vs objectAtIndex:i]) removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Note : enumerating harms modification but not iterating...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and Best way is

```
 for(UIView *subview in [scrollView subviews]) {

     [subview removeFromSuperview];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(subview) in self.scrollView.subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```