# How to implement UIScrollView into SwitchViewController app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I've got quite a problem with `UIScrollView` - I have a `SwitchViewController` (which is the root controller) with a method

```
-(BaseView*)loadView:(EActiveWindow)nextView`
```

Now, I found some quite useful info on the internet, but something is missing or I'm not loading views correctly. In the `loadView` method I have created a few view controllers if you choose an option from menu and I switch view finally with something like this:

```
activeView.controller = self;
[self.view insertSubview:activeView.view atIndex:0];
currentController = activeView;
return activeView;
```

Every view controller chosen initialized in root view controller is a `BaseView` object, where `BaseView : UIViewController`.

I checked one solution from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMv154TWTr8 and it worked, but I guess that problem is in my root controller where I kill and create views, which causes non scrolling screen - any thoughts, anybody?

**EDIT:**
If it somehow relevant - content of this scroll view will be changed depending on user's choices (text & images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it's not about switching views in root controller

after reading [this tutorial](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/) I managed to implement correctly UIScrollView :)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310723/how-to-remove-subviews-from-scrollview) helped me with clearing UIScrollView content before loading new data :)

to bo stack-correct ;) I include explicite my solution:
1) I added `IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView` to my UIView class
2) I added to my class implementation this, to initialize my scrollView with proper size

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 45, 280, 370)];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(280, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView release];
        ...
```

3) then I added to viewWillAppear method block of code creating few UITextView and putting them into scrollView, finally resize scrollView and voila :)

```
int newHeight = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [myObjectArray count]; i++) {
    Object *tmpObject = [myObjectArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (tmpObject) {
        //here goes initialization of an UITextView or whatever you need inside UIScrollView
        [self.scrollView addSubview:myTextView];
        [self resizeTextViewHeight:myTextView];
        newHeight += myTextView.bounds.size.height + 10;
        [myTextView release];
    }
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, newHeight);
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```