# Remove the content in a UIScrollView Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

How do you remove the content in a UIScrollView Programmatically? As I have to update the content in it frequently.

Comment: just use the `scrollView = nil` and `scrollView = [UIScrollView alloc] init];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310723/how-to-remove-subviews-from-scrollview

Comment: @Gray I believe you are correct. I believe I could have found my answer in there. But I spent quite a long time looking for the answer to this an never came across it. But I was searching for removing content from the UIScrollView not the subviews so that is  probably why I didn't find it. Thanks +1.

Comment: Np @john.  I was just adding that for posterity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through your scroll view's subviews like:

```
for(UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews)
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
```

or you can use `- [NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]` method like:

```
[scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that there is a difference between typical UIView:

```
for (UIView *v in [scrollView subviews])
    [v removeFromSuperView];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for(UIView *vw in [scrView subViews])
  [vw removeFromSuperView];
```

You can use this to remove contents in your scrollview

Answer (score 4):

Following code is use to remove object in scroll view

```
[[myScrollView viewWithTag:myButtonTag] removeFromSuperview];
```