# Remove subview from non present view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, subview

I have an scrollview in my app.
If I click on a Button on one Page, a Subview is added. I want to remove this subview when the user scrolls the view. This function is called:

```
-(void) DisableViews {
    [Annimation removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"scroll");
}
```

I get the NSLog many times, but the view also is Subview when i come back to the page.

I think this will happen, because the view with the subview is not the present view at this time, so i can't remove the subview.

Is there any possibility to remove a subview from any view on the subview?

edit:
ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

//...

    UIView *Annimation;



}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIView *Annimation;
```

Implementation:

```
 ViewController.m

 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import "AppDelegate.h"




 @implementation ViewController

 @synthesize Annimation;


 //...

 - (void) Bild1ButtonKlickt{
     Annimation = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
     Annimation.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     [self.view addSubview:Annimation]; 
}
```

Comment: That NSLog is rather useless. Make it `NSLog(@"remove ℅@", [Animation description]);`.

Comment: my NSLog is only to see if this function is called

Comment: It should also tell if `Animation` is non-nil.

Comment: I know what you mean, but if I start scrolling, `Annimation` is always nil

Comment: Please add the definition for Annmation as wll as the properties, the synthesize and the creation.

Comment: With `Annimation = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:...` you're not using the setter method. Use `self.Annimation = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:...`, later `[self.Annimation removeFormSuperview]` followed by `self.Annimation = nil;` to release it.

Comment: but still the view isn't removed: NSLog --> remove (null)

Comment: Is that the only subview in that scrollview? Anyway, one of the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310723/how-to-remove-subviews-from-scrollview should work.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you please post this as an answer and not as a comment, because I want to mark it as solution. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested as answer: Is that the only subview in that scrollview? Anyway, one of the answers from [how to remove subviews from scrollview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310723/how-to-remove-subviews-from-scrollview) should work.

Now which answer from the above page did fix it?

Comment: [[myScrollView viewWithTag:AnnimationTag] removeFromSuperview]; I added a Tag to my Annimation View and then it works

Answer (score 1):

Most likely "Annimation" (which I assume is an ivar) is `nil` at this point, and so nothing is happening when you try to remove it.

(As a note, don't access your ivars directly this way. Your property should be called `animationView` (to make it clear it's a view and not an `NSAnimation`, and you should access it via `self.animationView`. Also, methods should always have a leading lowercase. ObjC is very sensitive to method and property naming. Proper naming matters for the runtime; it's not just stylistic.)

Comment: the name was just for testing, i'll rename it later.  But I can't user self.animationView, because the property was not found