# Reducing the size of scrollview after removing subviews from scrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, scrollview

I want to remove subviews from scrollview, and saw this post: [how to remove subviews from scrollview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310723/how-to-remove-subviews-from-scrollview)

I am using this code to remove the subviews:

```
NSArray *subviews = [[scroller subviews] copy];
for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But I need to reduce the size of the scrollview?

How do I do that?

This is how I am removing a particular view:

```
        NSArray *subviews = [[menuScrollView subviews] copy];

        for (UIView *subview in subviews)
        {
            NSLog(@"subview.name is %i",subview.tag);
            if(subview.tag == 1001)
            {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
                break;
            }

        }
```

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
[mScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(mScrollView.frame.size.width,mScrollView.frame.size.height-subview.frame.size.height)];
```

But it is still not working...

Comment: size means height width?

Comment: What you need actually ?

Comment: @lakesh you are removing all the subViews of the scrollView? Why are you tring to reduce the size of the scrollView.

Comment: @Anupdas i used this code to remove a particular view, now I need to reduce the size of the scrollview...

Comment: @Manohar after removing a particular view in the scrollview, I need to reduce the size of the scrollview accordingly...

Comment: @lakesh On removing a specific subView, have you written any other code to change the layout of scrollView subViews. And by size you want to reduce only height/width. If that's so you can find the contentSize of the scrollView and then reduce the respective from the contentSize and set it. But this approach only work if you remove the last view from the scrollView.

Comment: by size, i mean the height. Can't u remove a view-> and reduce the size accordingly?

Comment: Any Luck on this ?

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
[[scrollVw subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

you will be succeed

Comment: The question was to adjust the contentSize of scrollView on removing subViews.